# Get the facebook User name using the API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm trying to get the facebook user name using the API

this is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $this->app_id,
  'secret' => $this->app_secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));



$session = $facebook->getUser();

$me = null;
if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        echo $uid;
        exit();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo $me;
        exit();
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
    $personLastName= $me['last_name'];

    var_dump($personLastName);
    exit();
```

the line where it crashes:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

No errors displayed, just white page and no log error in apache

Some help would be welcome!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are try to print the first element and then you have terminate the statement with `exit;` then the rest of the code will not be executed.Try this

```
$me = null;
if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        echo $uid;

        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo $me;

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
    $personLastName= $me['last_name'];

    var_dump($personLastName);
    exit();
}
```